# Is it safe to add OEM Renault green coolant to yellow coolant already present?

Tags: coolant, renault

I want to fill up the coolant of my Renault Clio III because it's at the minimum level. I've bought a bottle of official Renault GLACEOL RX type D coolant. This new one has a greenish/yellow color but the coolant already present in the reservoir has a light yellow color. Is it OK to mix them up as I've learned you may not mix different coolant colors? Or is it possible that the coolant present is some kind of one-size-fits-all coolant (my garage is not an official dealership).

Comment: The color is just added color.  Be sure you go by the specification in your Owner's manual vs. what is printed on the bottle.

Comment: On the bottle the exact same specification is printed as per user manual, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  The color is not indicative of what type of coolant it is.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't have an effect as long as it's meant for your vehicle.

Comment: OK you mean as long as I use the coolant as prescribed by the manufacturer it's ok to fill up? I have to say that the new coolant is green/yellowish color depending of the light, so it's possible that the coolant already present is the same. Just want to be 100% sure. Thanks

Comment: Yes. That is correct.